# Equality about integral on unit sphere, involving Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, spherical-harmonics

I met an equality in the book "Harmonic analysis and approximation on the unit sphere" by Wang Kunyang, in page 23. I cannot follow the reasoning below,

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega_{n}} P^{n}_{k}(\xi\cdot\eta)P^{n}_{j}(\xi\cdot\eta)d\omega_{n}(\eta)=\int_{[-1,1]}\int_{\Omega_{n-1}}P^{n}_{k}(t)P^{n}_{j}(t)d\omega_{n-1}d\mu(t)
\end{align}

where $\Omega_{n}$ is the unit sphere in $R^{n}$, $\xi$ is in $\Omega_{n}$ and fixed,  $P^{n}_{k}$ is a polynomial on $[-1,1]$ and $\mu$ is a measure defined on $\mathscr{E}$ which is a collection of Lebesgue measurable sets included in $[-1,1]$. $\mu$ is defined as 
$$\mu(E)=\int_{[-1,1]}\chi_{E}(t)(1-t^{2})^{\frac{n-3}{2}}dt, \quad\quad E\in\mathscr{E}$$

where $\chi_{E}$ is the characteristic function of $E$.

I think the precise definition of $\mu$ does not matter here. My problem is I don't understand how we can derive the right-hand side from the left-hand side of the equality. Whay $\mu$ is defined this way and how does the $\mu$ come in the reasoning?:-(

Comment: Consider $n=3$, then everything is intuitive:  on the left you have a function of the projection of $\eta\in B_1(0)$ onto the line $\{c\xi:c\in\Bbb{R}\}$, which is integrated over $B_1(0)$, the solid unit sphere.  Each point of that line corresponds to a disc of a certain radius perpendicular to that line; the integral over the sphere is the integral over [-1,1] of the integrals over the discs.  I think, however, that the exponent $(n-3)/2$ can't be right because then $\mu$ is just Lebesgue measure on $[-1,1]$ in the case $n=3$, and you're in effect integrating over a cylinder.

Comment: I think the precise definition (almost) always matters in mathematics; how is $\omega$ defined? Are you trying to prove the first equation under the definition of $\mu$ given in the second equation?

Comment: @ForgotALot Thanks very much for this comment. But I guess you misunderstand one point there. The $\Omega_{n}$ is the unit sphere (centered at origin), not the solid unit ball. It is just the surface of the ball, so...:-)

Comment: @Squirtle according to the book, the $d\omega_{n}$ denotes the surface element of $\Omega_{n}$. No precise definition is offered. Actually, I am not quite sure what it means here.

Comment: OK, my comment still holds, only instead of $B_1(0)$ we have $S^2=\Omega_3$ (unit sphere, not solid, in $\Bbb{R}^3$), and instead of discs we have circles of varying radii $r$, say $r\Omega_2$.  The integral over $[-1,1]$ of the integrals over the circles is still the integral over the sphere.  The circles need to have varying radii depending on where the projection falls so that the integral of the integrals is a correct integral over a sphere, which is why I still don't like the exponent.

Comment: @ForgotALot I guess that exponent has something to do with the measures of varying-radii circles in 3d case.

Comment: Have a look in the very first pages of Müller's "Spherical Harmonics" (or his later "Analysis of spherical symmetry in Euclidean space"), it is a classic in this kind of computations and more or less all those books on spherical-stuff have it in their bibliographies.

Comment: Specifically, what you need here is the equality $$d\omega_n=(1-t^2)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}dt d\omega_{n-1}, $$ where $t=\xi\cdot \eta$. [Here](https://negropeppe.wordpress.com/2016/04/03/calculus-on-the-sphere/) there are some rough notes I wrote about this computation, but they are not meant to be read by anyone else than myself, so if you find them unclear please switch to Müller's books.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for this reference. I'll check it out.